# TFS Deploy Agent run remote powershell issue

Tags: continuous-deployment, powershell-remoting

We have a script language application. I'm wanting to have CI deployment on the dev server. I set up a the deploy definition in TFS to have a step Run Powershell on Remote Machine. However running into failure that I can't figure out.  I've already `Enable-PSRemote -f` on the remote server `dev-cf2016`.   I've verified that remoted into the TFS server as myself, I can run:

```
Invoke-Cmd -computername dev-cf2016 -scriptblock {Get-ChildItem C:\}
```

or any other command.  The TFSService account is a local administrator on the TFS server.

```
2018-06-12T20:36:19.5073933Z Deployment status for machine 'dev-cf2016:5986' : 'Failed'
2018-06-12T20:36:19.6011353Z 
2018-06-12T20:36:19.6011353Z 
2018-06-12T20:36:19.6011353Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: 
    Connecting to remote server dev-cf2016 failed with the following error message : 
    The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the 
    service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and 
    documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly 
    IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the 
    destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more 
    information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. 
---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Connecting to remote server 
    dev-cf2016 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the 
    destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is
    running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the 
    WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. 
    If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination 
    to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information, 
    see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Comment: What account is the Visual Studio Team Services Bulld Agent running under?

Comment: It's a bad practice to make the TFS Service Account a local admin.

Comment: yea i didn't really want to. but someone said the agent should have admin role so i tried it out.  doesn't work anyway.   

the agent is running under an AD user"TFSService" specific to TFS.

Comment: trying different things on the defintion, i changed the winRM method to unencrypted HTTP and the command worked.   so question then becomes...what SSL certificate do I need where?    We have IIS on the remote server  with an SSL cert, but what cert is winRM using?

Comment: for future readers:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https